# Summing MAX and MIN values in the same column

Tags: sql, sum, max, min

I am trying to pull payroll data and need to add the maximum and minimum value in a column [PAYRATE] to come up with an average rate.  The table can have multiple lines for a paycheck with the same pay rate so AVG[PAYRATE]  will not work.   I tried the code below but it failed.  Can this be done?

```
(SELECT SUM((MAX(payrate))+(MIN(payrate)))
FROM    PAYCHECKS
WHERE PAYROLCD in ('01', '02') 
AND PYRLRTYP = 1 
AND EMPLOYID = A.EMPLOYID 
AND PYADNMBR = A.PYADNMBR) AS PAYRATE
```

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the outer `sum`:

```
SELECT (MAX(payrate)+MIN(payrate))/2 AS PAYRATE
FROM    PAYCHECKS
WHERE PAYROLCD in ('01', '02') 
AND PYRLRTYP = 1 
AND EMPLOYID = A.EMPLOYID 
AND PYADNMBR = A.PYADNMBR
```

I added a `/2` for the average.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do average of Minimum and Maximum values. Also, you need to divide by decimal 2 to get accurate results otherwise if you divide just by 2, decimal result would be truncated. You may alter scale and precision according to your need below.

```
SELECT ((MIN(payrate)+MAX(payrate))/CAST(2 AS DECIMAL (9,2)) AS PAYRATE
FROM    PAYCHECKS
WHERE PAYROLCD in ('01', '02') 
AND PYRLRTYP = 1 
AND EMPLOYID = A.EMPLOYID 
AND PYADNMBR = A.PYADNMBR
```